# Calculating client size and position from Window Rect

Tags: c++, winapi

How do I get the client size and position with window rect? Is this possible?

Comment: A rect is just left, right, top, bottom, it's not connected to anything in particular. Can you explain more what you're trying to do? Where did this rect come from?

Comment: I need getting window client size and position from RECT structure (like inverse AdjustWindowRectEx), RECT structure comes from WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING message and LPARAM.

Comment: That message gives you a struct with the hwnd in it. Why wouldn't you use that to get the additional data you need? It also doesn't really give you a rect, although you could construct one from the x,y,w,h data in the struct.

Comment: It's gives a Window Rect, I need a construct "client" rect from window rect.

Comment: The lparam is a pointer to a WINDOWPOS structure that gives you the hwnd of the window. Use `GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);`

Comment: This feels like an XY question where you're not telling us the problem you really want to solve, only what you've decided is the way to solve it, which may not be the best way. You might consider explaining the whole problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Send the window a `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to find out. Maybe try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    RECT r;
    HWND h = GetConsoleWindow(); // or whatever window needed

    GetWindowRect(h, &r);
    std::cout << "Relative Client X,Y: " << r.left << "," << r.top << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Relative Client W,H: " << r.right - r.left << "," << r.bottom - r.top << std::endl;

    GetClientRect(h, &r);
    std::cout << "Client X,Y: " << r.left << "," << r.top << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Client W,H: " << r.right - r.left << "," << r.bottom - r.top << std::endl;
}
```

For example:

```
Relative Client X,Y: 100,100
Relative Client W,H: 947,594
Client X,Y: 0,0
Client W,H: 910,552
```

And/or if you want to get client area position relative to the screen, you can use [ClientToScreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd183434(v=vs.85).aspx) function. For example:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HWND h = GetConsoleWindow(); // or provided HWND
    POINT p{}; // defaulted to 0,0 which is always left and top of client area

    ClientToScreen(h, &p);
    SetCursorPos(p.x, p.y); // places cursor to the 0,0 of the client
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a window RECT, the upper left corner is the window position and also you can calculate the size using upper left and lower-right corners of the window.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I need a client rectangle, not window rectangle.

Comment: If you have the window handle, you can get it by using GetClientRect . [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633503(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
RECT GetClientRectFromWindowRect(HWND hWnd, RECT rect)
{
    RECT v = { 0 };
    AdjustWindowRectEx(&v, 
        GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE), 
        !!GetMenu(hWnd), 
        GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
        );
    RECT ret = { 0 };
    ret.bottom = rect.bottom - v.bottom;
    ret.left = rect.left - v.left;
    ret.right = rect.right - v.right;
    ret.top = rect.top - v.top;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Brittle. This doesn't work for all window styles/combinations, and fails to account for a menu bar that wraps. But seeing that you are initializing a rectangle `v` to all zero, and then move on to set all coordinates to zero again, you have bigger problems to sort out. Also completely unclear, why are doing the most obscure acrobatics instead of simply negating all coordinates.

Comment: because it’s a copy-paste from [Old New Thing, What is the inverse of AdjustWindowRect and AdjustWindowRectEx?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131017-00/?p=2903)